# Logon script in windows 11 with "run only specified windows applications"

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, group-policy, windows-11

I'm a begginer/student trying to manually setup a kiosk mode on windows 11 for educational purposes. I have set the group policy "run only specified windows applications" alongside a logon batch script

```
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -file C:\KeepEdgeRunning.ps1
```

It's to start a PowerShell script that keeps MS Edge maximized.

```
function Set-WindowStyle { #copied this from the internet
param(
[Parameter()]
[ValidateSet('FORCEMINIMIZE', 'HIDE', 'MAXIMIZE', 'MINIMIZE', 'RESTORE', 
             'SHOW', 'SHOWDEFAULT', 'SHOWMAXIMIZED', 'SHOWMINIMIZED', 
             'SHOWMINNOACTIVE', 'SHOWNA', 'SHOWNOACTIVATE', 'SHOWNORMAL')]
$Style = 'SHOW',
[Parameter()]
$MainWindowHandle = (Get-Process -Id $pid).MainWindowHandle
)
$WindowStates = @{
    FORCEMINIMIZE   = 11; HIDE            = 0
    MAXIMIZE        = 3;  MINIMIZE        = 6
    RESTORE         = 9;  SHOW            = 5
    SHOWDEFAULT     = 10; SHOWMAXIMIZED   = 3
    SHOWMINIMIZED   = 2;  SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7
    SHOWNA          = 8;  SHOWNOACTIVATE  = 4
    SHOWNORMAL      = 1
}
Write-Verbose ("Set Window Style {1} on handle {0}" -f $MainWindowHandle, $($WindowStates[$style]))

$Win32ShowWindowAsync = Add-Type –memberDefinition @” 
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
“@ -name “Win32ShowWindowAsync” -namespace Win32Functions –passThru




$Win32ShowWindowAsync::ShowWindowAsync($MainWindowHandle, $WindowStates[$Style]) | Out-Null}


while($true){
$edge = Get-Process -name "msedge" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($edge -eq $null){
    $edge = Start-Process "msedge"
}
Foreach($proc in $edge){ #maximizing all subproceses, one of them is the main window
    Set-WindowStyle -MainWindowHandle $proc.MainWindowHandle -Style MAXIMIZE
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
```

}

Problem is I'm not sure what applications to enable for the group policy. I have enabled powershell.exe, cmd.exe, msedge.exe. However the function `Set-WindowStyle` uses external libraries, I'm unsure whether any programs need to be enabled in order for those to work.

The script works fine, just not when the policy is enabled. Maybe it's not because of the script itself but Windows 11 Insider Preview acting up or something I don't understand about gpo yet. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Why are you still using an Insider Preview build when a retail stable build is available?  What build are you using if not the stable build?

Comment: Thank you, I will update and maybe it will help.

Comment: @JanisL. Furthermore, if you have trouble with it after you run updates/upgrade, you should consider adding verbosity to your commands in the script to log of `write-output` and then use `Start-Transcript c:\log\trans.log` or something like that and look it over once the user account logs in, etc. This will help you understand if there are any PowerShell errors that need rectified for it to complete. At the end of the script, just add `Stop-Transcript` and that'll stop it. Ensure the `C:\Logs` or whatever local file system folder you put those to exists beforehand.

Comment: @JanisL. Also, in case it's a problem with execution policy restrictions, use: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -windowstyle hidden -file C:\KeepEdgeRunning.ps1` and see if that helps if you still have trouble; maybe start with that post your upgrade process of the Windows OS.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Thanks, it works now, I'm not sure whether it was the update or `ExecutionPolicy Bypass` but it's working fine now :)

Comment: Just remove the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` from the command and run the task or let it be triggered to confirm. If it works without that, then you know it was the update at least.

Comment: @JanisL. Since you said you are a beginner, consider testing with and using `if(!$edge)` rather than `if($edge -eq $null)`. If it's a matter of true or false this should work just fine **or** changing the logic execution to run what's needed if the variable is true e.g. `if($edge)`. Might as well iron it out while you're learning if you can.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Damn, I'm sorry, but I had forgotten to add the policy on the new system (after upgrade), so it still didn't work after I added it :(. However, on the bright side, I figured out on my own, that it's the batch script causing issues. If I only run a .ps1 script it works fine. Apparently I didn't even need to allow any programs besides MS Edge for the script to run (not even PowerShell). Albeit, I still get "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions..." irregardless of whether I set a script to run. Also thank you for the tip with `!$edge`.

Comment: I'm not sure of your specific GP settings but things that stick out for the batch script not running... User **Config | Admin Templates | System | Don't run specified Windows apps** and confirm that cmd.exe is not listed.  Also if the batch is on a network UNC path drive, you might have to add the FQDN server name to the [Site to Zone Assignment List](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::IZ_Zonemaps). I always add the FQDN as one entry and just the server name as another or those and full path to the script that runs with the GPO.

Comment: Another thought also would be to have the batch script copied over to the local file system and then have the GPO point to it there rather than UNC path. And another thought would be to take the cmd batch out of the loop and run pure PowerShell and but whatever batch logic into a PS script, etc. If you are using batch to execute PowerShell.exe, that is not required if Task Scheduler is the issue figuring out how to get it to execute the PowerShell without the batch script, I can give you advice there is needed too @JanisL.